# Python Django how to interact and link from one app to another?

Tags: python, django

I created an app called 'user' that has all of the login, registration, and logout (user/login, user/registration, user/logout) logic using the Django's User model. If the user logs in, how do I redirect them to a different app, say, 'posts' where they can view a list of different posts? Here's the main urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('user/', include("user.urls")),
]
```

Also, if I wanted to create a view for the main index page, do I create a views.py file in the main folder and add a path to that page? What would that path look like?

I am trying to teach myself everything so let me know if there are some gaps of information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in main `url.py` default comment section:

```
"""
[...]
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
```

### Example

This is your main `url.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('user.urls'))
]
```

Inside your **user app's** directory create a new file named `urls.py` with following content:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/foo/', user.foo_user_view, name='foo_url_name'),
    path('user/bar/', user.bar_user_view, name='bar_url_name'),
]
```

**Note**: `.` in `from . import views` import statement stays for **user app's** `urls.py` directory.

Also, if you want to import specific views, simply use `from user.views import foo_user_view`

After this you will be able to access your **user app's** views through:

- https://localhost:8000/user/foo/
- https://localhost:8000/user/bar/